# Defining functions in SproutCore fixtures

Tags: sproutcore

Is it possible to define a function from inside a SproutCore fixture? For example, if I wanted an array controller that changed the function applied to an object dependent on the selection. I've tried specifying an attribute in the model as below:

```
func: SC.Record.attr(Object)
```

and in the fixtures as:

```
{guid: 'tool-0', 
 func: function(){
   $('domObject').append('message');
 }
}
```

But I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'func' of object App.Tool({guid: tool-0 , func: function() { ... }}) READY_CLEAN is not a function
```

Is the problem with my implementation or my approach here? I'm not brilliant with Javascript to begin with, and there isn't a wealth of information about using Sproutcore, so I'm struggling to tell if I'm using it correctly.

Comment: what are you trying to do, modify the view from within the model object?

Comment: At the moment, I'm trying to perform functions on an HTML5 canvas element in the DOM, with the function performed dependent on the selection of an ArrayController. Think Rectangle tool, Ellipse tool, etc. However, I want the functions to eventually be stored in a database or similar, hence why I'm using the store. I'd like to be able to call App.toolController.get('content').func(); or similar, if possible.

Comment: Additionally, it works fine if I call the function like App.Tool.FIXTURES[0].func(), but obviously this is a bad approach. The problem seems to arise once I'm trying to access the object from an ArrayController or ObjectController.

Comment: I've got it working, but it feels like a very messy way of going about it, I'm having to use:

App.toolController.get('content').store.dataHashes[App.toolController.get('content').storeKey].func()

I'm sure there's a much nicer way.

Comment: there might be, but im not sure how you would do it.

Comment: OK, I'll stick with this for now as it seem to work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add functions in the fixtures file. Fixtures are designed only for holding data in the development phase of an application.

If you want to add any functions which manipulates the existing data or properties of an each object, define those functions in Model.